# Rails: Adding Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a `join_table` that currently has the following columns:

```
     - id
     - table_a_id
     - table_b_id
```

Attempting to add a foreign key constraint to `join_table` for `table_a_id`, I generate the following migration:

```
    class AddTableIdForeignKeyConstraintToJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]  
      def change
        add_foreign_key :table_a, :join_table, column: :table_a_id, primary_key: "lng_id"
      end
    end
```

**Error**:

```
    PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "question_id" referenced in
    foreign key constraint does not exist 
    : ALTER TABLE "table_a" ADD CONSTRAINT 
      "fk_rails_4b0148d527"
      FOREIGN KEY ("question_id")
      REFERENCES "join_table" ("lng_id")
```

**Questions**
What does this line mean `foreign key constraint does not exist`? Where is Rails looking for the `foreign key`?

Comment: Did you get any solution to your issue ?

Comment: not yet @dkp. I got the initial error to go away but I am a bit confused about how referencing works. For example: now I am trying to add a foreign key constraint for `table_b` to the join table and getting the error that `constraint "fk_rails_ff820b2696" for relation "join_table" already exists`. This means that the method `add_foreign_key` does not do what I think it does. So now working on understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error means is that there is no column `question_id` in table `table_a`. The table that you are adding the foreign key to (`join_table`) should be the first argument and primary key should point to `id` column in `table_a`

Answer (score 0):

As per [**add_foreign_key**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key) , first argument should be the table in which the foreign key exists, second argument should be table name in which the corresponding primary key exists.

And, your error indicates foreign key does not exist where it should.

Try changing the migration to this:

```
def change
    add_foreign_key :join_table, :table_a, column: :table_a_id, primary_key: "lng_id"
 end
```